# Trigger an action when an user clicks on a cell in swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm creating an app using Swift.
I have an `UITableView` that I populate with some data from a database. When user clicks on a cell, I would like to trigger an action.

What I have done :

```
var array: [String] = ["example"]


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return array.count
    }



    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = UITableViewCell(style :UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.textLabel.text = array[indexPath.row]
        cell.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.targetForAction("getAction:", withSender: self)
        return cell
    }

    func getAction(sender:UITableViewCell)->Void {
        if(sender.tag == 0) {
            println("it worked")
        }
    }
```

I tried to adapt a solution from an another post but I did it definitely wrong. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Implement `UITableViewDelegate` and use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

you can use the `indexPath` to get the item from your collection and perform your action

Comment: Thank you, that's perferct!

Comment: don't forget to implement `UITableViewDelegate` protocol to get `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method

Answer (score 10):

In Swift 4, I believe the method has changed ever so slightly:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // your code
}
```